# responsive background image not resizing

Tags: html, css

My college asked me to code a site for a project but make it responsive. The image i'm using for the header background is not resizing.
This is the code for the HTML

```
 <div id="headerbackground"></div>
```

And for the style i've put

```
#headerbackground {
background-image: url('../images/header.png');
background-size: contain;
max-width:100%;
max-height: 100%;
}
```

I've followed a few tutorials but no luck

Comment: Make sure to add `background-repeat: no-repeat`. Otherwise by default it would repeat the image and not resize (I believe).

Comment: I've added the background-repeat in so the code is: `#headerbackground {
background-image: url('../images/header.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
max-width:100%;
max-height: 100%;
}`
But still no luck on the resizing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set an empty div background until you set a height on that. Or you have some content inside that div. So all you need to set the height of the div.
So here is your responsive background image. You can check responsiveness  resizing the window.

```css
body {

  margin: 0;
}

#headerbackground {
  background: url('http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2098/2260149771_00cb406fd6_o.jpg');
  background-size:100% 100%; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerbackground"></div>
```

Comment: Thankyou all for fast responses, The help you are providing is great. I think i have worded the question stupidly, @Mostafa thats for a full background i only need a certain size, but when i put in the height needed it stays at that size doesn't resize fully, Or can it not do that?

Comment: what is your certain size

Answer (score 1):

First, you haven't specified a minimum height, only a maximum, so it's collapsing to 0.

Second, you probably want to use `background-size:cover;` - that resizes the image to *cover* the whole element. *Contain* resizes the image so that the whole thing only *fits within* the element.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#headerbackground {
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/g/800/600');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerbackground"></div>
```

Comment: We had it from a PSD, so it's not one full image?, It's the header that i'm attempting to make responsive but it's still not going anywhere with the above.
[http://www.heachi.com/college/webtotal/index1.html]

Comment: The image is scaling as you resize the window. What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I worded the question stupidly i do apologise, It's one of many background images needed if that makes sense it's only the header part needed

Comment: Since it's a header, you're probably going to insert a menu or other content in there. You can change the min-height value to whatever suits your design.